# How to access an array when it is within an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The overall goal of what I'm trying to do is to compare a string to index 0 of an array (that is held within an arraylist), and if the strings are the same (ignoring case), call a method that matches the case of the string to the translated word (held at index 1 of the array inside an arraylist). When I run this code and I print out the contents of my translated arraylist, I get all "no match" characters. I'm assuming this is because I'm not accessing the index I want in the correct manner. Please help!

```
public static String translate(String word, ArrayList<String[]> wordList) { 
    if (word == "." || word == "!" || word == ";" || word == ":") {
        return word;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
            String origWord = wordList.get(i)[0];
            String transWord = wordList.get(i)[1];

            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(origWord)) { //FIXME may need to change if you need to switch from translated to original
                String translated = matchCase(word, transWord);
                return translated;
            }
    }
    String noMatch = Character.toString(Config.LINE_CHAR);     


    return noMatch;
}
```

**Sample Data and expected result**

word = "hello"

wordList.get(i)[0] = "Hello"

wordList.get(i)[1] = "Hola"

(word and wordList.get(i)[0] match, so the next step is executed)

match case method is called and returns the translated word with the same case as the original word ->

translated = "hola"

returns the translated word.

(the for loop iterates through the entire wordList until it finds a match, then it calls the translate method)

**

**Match Case's Code**

```
 public static String matchCase(String template, String original) {
    String matched = "";
    if (template.length() > original.length()) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= original.length(); i++) {
            if (template.charAt(i-1) >= 'a' &&  template.charAt(i-1) <= 'z') {

                if (i == original.length()) {

                matched +=  original.substring(original.length() - 1).toLowerCase();

                }
                else {

                    matched += original.substring((i-1), i).toLowerCase();
                }

            }
            else if (template.charAt(i-1) >= 'A' && template.charAt(i-1) <= 'Z') {
                if (i == original.length()) {

                    matched += original.substring(original.length() - 1).toUpperCase();

                }
                else {

                    matched +=  original.substring((i-1), i).toUpperCase();

                }
            }
        }
        return matched;
     }
     else if (template.length() < original.length()) {
         int o;
            original.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 1; i <= template.length(); i++) {
                if (template.charAt(i-1) >= 'a' &&  template.charAt(i-1) <= 'z') {
                    if (i == template.length()) {
                        matched += original.substring(original.length() - 1).toLowerCase();
                    }
                    else {
                        matched += original.substring((i-1), i).toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
                else if (template.charAt(i-1) >= 'A' && template.charAt(i-1) <= 'Z') {
                    if (i == template.length()) {
                        matched += original.substring(original.length() - 1).toUpperCase();
                    }
                    else {
                        matched += original.substring((i-1), i).toUpperCase();
                    }
                }
                String newMatched = matched + original.substring(i, original.length() - 1);
                matched = newMatched;
                newMatched = "";
            }

            return matched;
     }

   return original; 
}
```

Comment: It should also be nice to provide `matchCase`'s code

Comment: You're accessing the elements in the correct way. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: word == "." ? word.equals(".") rather?

Comment: Yes there are some remarks we could make such as using `equals` method intead of `==`operator or set `NoMatch` as a constant (`final static`) but it doesn't seem to be the root cause here.

Comment: Have you tested `matchCase` separately? It seems to make problems when template is longer than the translated word.

Comment: matchCase is definitely causing me problems, but I think that's a seperate issue, since the translate method only returns the noMatch character if String word doesn't equal any word in the wordList.

Comment: Huh? That's exactly what you wrote though, if you don't match any original word at `.get(i)[0]`, then you return `noMatch`. Whereas #matchCase is full of problems, explain the necessity / usage for `#matchCase` in more detail

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it works rather well with the example you have provided. I cannot help for your bug.

There are however some bugs to notify and improvement to suggest:

1. `matchCase` fails when template is shorter than the translated word.
2. Never compare strings with `==`. Use the `equals` method and look [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1153988) .
3. This is not really important but why is `noMatch` always computed. Why don't you declare it as a constant once?

   `public static final String NO_MATCH = String.valueOf(Config.LINE_CHAR);`
4. More importantly I think that `matchCase` is not really pertinent by design and is over complicated. I think that You should just determine if the word to translate is all lower case or upper case or with the first letter in uppercase and the following letters in lower case. What you do (comparing the case letter by letter) is not really pertinent when the length is different.
5. When you consider a single character, use `charAt` instead of `substring`it is simpler and faster.
6. You also might have a look a [regex](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to analyze your Strings.
7. Have you considered [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s for your translation lookup?

...